# Dropdown menu items hides behind main menu in bootstrap customized navigation bar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I am trying to create Navigation bar in bootstrap. Have added customized styles in bootstrap-theme.min.css file. This way I am able to created navigation bar but dropdown menu items get hide behind main menu in small screen devices. The code and screenshots of output are as below:

Styles added in bootstrap-theme.min.css file:

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px; 
    background-image:url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.bizmerlin.net/bg_header.png'); 
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:100% 100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: rgba(70, 131, 176, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li, .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: #528cb4;
 height: 38px;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 margin-top:4px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: 6px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 line-height: 10px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:focus {
 background-color: #7fbb00;  
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(233, 129, 42, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #e9812a;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #e9812a;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #e9812a;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #4683b0;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #528cb4;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #aeff00;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #528cb4;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #7fbb00;
 height: 36px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
.caret {
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
}
```

HTML code for navigation bar is:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Bootstrap 3 Responsive Layout Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

 </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li style="background-color:#e9812a;"><a href="/">Home1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
     <li><a href="">asf</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="">Analytics</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> 
 <div class="container">        

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:[image]

The dropdown menu hides behind Contactus and Anlytics. Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance. Let me know if my question is not clear.

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/38fmg5h3/2/

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE : I added this to your css

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    height:38px;
}
```

and removed `height:38px;` from `#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li, .navbar-brand`. That should do the trick.

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px; 
    background-image:url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.bizmerlin.net/bg_header.png'); 
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:100% 100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: rgba(70, 131, 176, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    height:38px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li, .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: #528cb4;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 margin-top:4px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: 6px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 line-height: 10px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:focus {
 background-color: #7fbb00;  
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(233, 129, 42, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #e9812a;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #e9812a;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #e9812a;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #4683b0;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #528cb4;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #aeff00;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #528cb4;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #7fbb00;
 height: 36px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
.caret {
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li style="background-color:#e9812a;"><a href="/">Home1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
     <li><a href="">asf</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="">Analytics</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> 
 <div class="container">        

 </div>
```

Working JSFiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/38fmg5h3/1/

Comment: Thanks for reply. But its not working. It displayes the dropdown menu but hides last Menu item "Analytics". Moreover design got distorted on large screen on clicking dropdown menu.

Comment: @Tiya If i run the code snippet in my answer it is displaying the last menu item "Analytics". On what condition it is not displaying the "Analytics" menu item? And it works on my JSFiddle too.

Comment: Actually I am using bootstrap and those files are not there. May be that is the reason. Have tried it over my code in my system.

Comment: @Tiya When you open the page1 dropdown, how do want it to be displayed? Should it come on top of "contact us" and "analytics"? or "contact us" and "analytics" should be displayed after the dropdown is displayed? Can you specify that clearly?

Comment: All menu items should be shown as well as Drop down menu items. You can check any bootstrap menu. Please check here http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=dropdowns-within-navbar

Comment: @Tiya See my updated JSFiddle. I think this is what you needed.

Comment: Yes I need this. Please let me know what you have changed?

Comment: @Tiya See my updated answer. I have mentioned what i changed. If it works for you, can you please accept and upvote my answer? Thanks.